# What is the quickest way to hide SharePoint Elements on a Modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, css, modern-experience, spfx-extensions

I have a SharePoint modern site homepage which I am using as a landing page. Currently I am hiding the default elements in site like "Site Title" and "Logo" using custom CSS which is loaded with the extension.

But the problem is, whenever the page loads, the elements show for a little while and then hide when the CSS is loaded which is kind of ugly for a landing page. I am looking for ways to hide the elements as quickly as possible.

Currently Microsoft doesn't provide a solution to this so this has to be a custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the functions that can be set not to be used in the settings, there should be no faster way to hide other functions than the SharePoint extension.

[Optimize custom extension performance in SharePoint Online modern site pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/modern-custom-extensions?view=o365-worldwide)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no SharePoint out of the box or any other custom solution supported to hide SharePoint modern page elements.

As you already know, you can hide it using [SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions).

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Customizing "modern" team sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites)
2. [Customizing "modern" site pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages)
3. [Customizing the "modern" experiences in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations)